# Trying to add two conditions in if

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute this bash script, where I'm trying to join the domain.

After `domainjoin-cli` join `$Domain` it prompts for password and if my password is wrong I want script to exit with a msg "Not Successful" if on other hand it's the right password I need it to continue with the remaining part of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo -n "Domain: "  
read Domain  
domainjoin-cli join $Domain  
if [[ "$password" = 'SUCCESS' ]]  
then  
    echo "SUCCESS"  
    ls -l  
fi  
echo  
if [[ "$password" = 'Error' ]]  
    then  
        echo "Not SUCCESSFULL"  
        exit  
fi
```

If I Execute the script I get this error msg:

```
3.sh: 5: 3.sh: [[: not found  
3.sh: 10: 3.sh: [[: not found
```

This is the output if password is wrong:

```
"Error: LW_ERROR_PASSWORD_MISMATCH [code 0x00009c56] The password is incorrect for the given account"
```

This is the output if password is right:

```
"Warning: System restart required Your system has been configured to authenticate to Active Directory for the first time. It is recommended that you restart your system to ensure that all applications recognize the new settings.

SUCCESS"
```

Comment: (After indentation) it looks like you're missing an `fi` after `echo "SUCCESS"`.

Comment: After making the necessary changes I'm getting this error msg.

3.sh: 5: [: -eq: unexpected operator
3.sh: 10: [: -eq: unexpected operator

Comment: After editing, I'm having this  
"error 3.sh: 5: 3.sh: [[: not found"  

"3.sh: 10: 3.sh: [[: not found"

Comment: I don't see where you set `$password`; does it ever get set? Also, are you running the script with the `sh` command? If so, don't; that overrides the shebang and runs it with `sh` rather than `bash`. Instead just use `./scriptname` (or the path to it if it's not in the current directory).

Comment: Well $password is the input of "domainjoin-cli join $Domain".

Answer (score 2):

- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Quoting the variable ensures that it expands to a single "word" or argument when the script runs.
- `-eq` and the like are for comparing *numbers*, so it will treat "SUCCESS" as the number *zero*, which is not what you want.
- Don't be afraid of Bashisms. `[[` is preferable to `[`, because it's harder to break it.

The result:

```
[[ "$password" = 'SUCCESS' ]]
```